# Android Studio: How to affect multiple Views at the same time? (XML + Kotlin)

Tags: xml, list, android-studio, kotlin, imageview

I am trying to make it so when I hover over one of my 30 or so ImageViews, a grey background appears behind them. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this other than calling each ImageView individually. (I am writing the code in Kotlin, using id calls from my adjoined xml file in Android Studio.) For example, instead of saying:

```
if (binding.appleImg || binding.pizzaImg || binding.fishImg ....) {do stuff}
```

How can I just say something like:

```
if (groupOfFoodImages ...) {do stuff}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to know which elements you have in your layout programmatically, for that use below function:

```
    fun View.getAllChildren(): List<View> {
        val result = ArrayList<View>()
        if (this !is ViewGroup) {
            result.add(this)
        } else {
            for (index in 0 until this.childCount) {
                val child = this.getChildAt(index)
                result.addAll(child.getAllChildren())
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

Then loop through to find all `imageView`s and set their backgrounds. I am guessing you are using fragments, then call it like below:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        for(myView in view.getAllChildren()) {
            if (myView.javaClass.name.contains("ImageView")) {
                myView.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_background_image)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because you cannot assign a specific single object action (the one imageView you're hovering on) to a group of objects. What you can do instead without iterating the whole list, is a) override `onFocusChanged` and change the background that `hasFocus`. When focus change again you set back the old background and place the gray one to the new focus or, as you're in Kotlin b)  use composables and cooroutineScopes to understand which object is currently showing changing the background accordingly. I've done something similar to play a video when the object is visible, in my case was an auto slider built with LazyRow

```
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    var currentMediaIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    LaunchedEffect(currentMediaIndex) {
    while (true) {
        delay(MainActivity.mediaDelay)
        if (thisPlayer != null && !thisPlayer!!.isPlaying && medias.isNotEmpty()) {
            val nextIndex = (currentMediaIndex + 1) % medias.size
            currentMediaIndex = nextIndex
            coroutineScope.launch {
                listState.animateScrollToItem(currentMediaIndex)
                when (listState.isScrollInProgress) {
                    false -> {
                        if (vList.contains(currentMediaIndex))
                            thisPlayer!!.play()
                    }

                    else -> {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```